# python - write to txt file. the problem: some file names are ok, some file names get error

Tags: python

for example:

`testdata.txt` - is fine

`datatest.txt` - fail

it happens with a lot of file names, some names are just fine a lot of other names fail.

examples on screenshots:

Code with good name:

[image: code with good name]

the result:

[image: job done]

Code with bad name:

[image: code with bad name]

the result:

[image: error]

Comment: Please post text as text, not images of text.

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: we can't help you if you don't share your full code

Comment: I've made it so the pictures show up, but please please please do not post your code as pictures. No one here want's to transcribe from a picture to replicate or just talk about your code.

Comment: string \t is tab escape char

Comment: `\t` is a tab character.  You either need to double the backslashes to escape them, put a `r` in front to make it a *raw string literal*, or use forward slashes.

Comment: remember to use ```mf.close()```

Comment: If you want to get help from community, you should post the entire code. There might be problems that we cannot see it. Maybe there is problem with path (incorrect one) ....

Comment: sorry for the pictures instead of text. it was my first question here :-)  thank you all for the answers. the "\\" solved the error!

Answer (score 2):

That’s because `\t` means ASCII tab. Use r strings instead.
More info on both things on https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html

Comment: Do you mean `\t`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I had a different keyboard language and didn’t notice

Comment: We all make mistakes, but when you realized you've made one please [edit] your question or answer to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using raw strings for your variables, `r"H:\testdata.txt"` and `r"H:\datatest.txt"` or you can escape the backslashes like so `"H:\\testdata.txt"` and `"H:\\datatest.txt"`.